# Inline If Then Statement. ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I need to make a statement much like

```
<%#((bool)Eval("inactive")) ? "<span style='color:red;font-weight:600;'>INACTIVE</span>" : "<span style='color:green;font-weight:600;'>ACTIVE</span>"%>
```

Except instead of a boolean I need it to take 3 Conditional Statements.

So using

```
<%#Eval("Program_Num") %>
```

I need it to say

- If Program_Num == 1 then it's X,
- if Program_Num == 2 then it's y,
- if Program_Num == 3 then it's z;

I'll clarify and answer any questions to the best of my abilities, thank you for the help.

Comment: May not be as clean, but are <% if { %> <% } else if { %> blocks out of the question?

Comment: No. All answers are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
<%# (int)Eval("Program_Num") == 1 ? "X" : (int)Eval("Program_Num") == 2 ? "Y" : (int)Eval("Program_Num") == 3 ? "Z" : "default value" %>
```

It's like saying this.

```
if ((int)Eval("Program_Num") == 1)
    "X"
else if ((int)Eval("Program_Num") == 2)
    "Y"
else if ((int)Eval("Program_Num") == 3)
    "Z"
else
    "default value"
```

Comment: I'm glad you like my answer ^_^

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
<%#Eval("Program_Num") == 1 ? "X" : Eval("Program_Num") == 2 ? "y" : Eval("Program_Num") == 3 ? "z" %>
```

Obviously you need to substitute "x" "y" "z" with whatever you want it display.

Answer (score 0):

It's inelegant, but you could just use a nested version of it:

```
var x = Program_Num == 1 ? "X" : (Program_Num == 2 ? "x" : (Program_Num == 3 ? "y" : "DEFAULT"))
```

I've kept it as clean C# for clarity here. You can adapt it for ASP.NET.

If you're going to three levels, then it's really time to start using proper if or switch constructs though.